# Angular Radio button click show and hide not working

Tags: javascript, html, angular

I'm beginner for the Angular and  try to create Angular 5 ,when i click the radio button show and hide div area.
,I created `customer-1` and `customer-2` *radio button* when i click the customer-2 radio button is it not working (shown  1st div),That one is normal html to working fine, but it's not work for angular 5 ,
anyone know how to put that one correctly in Angular5?

Thanks

**html**

```
<div class="modal fade cust-my-modal cust-my-modal-2" id="signup_modal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel">
  <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">×</span></button>
        <h4 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel">SIGN UP</h4>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
        <div class="row">
          <div class="col-sm-12">
            <div class="top-radio">
              <div class="radio radio-primary">
                <input type="radio" name="radio1" id="radio1" onClick="changediv('nc_signup')" checked="checked" value="option1">
                <label for="radio1">
                 customers-1
                </label>
              </div>
              <div class="radio radio-primary">
                <input type="radio" name="radio1" id="radio2" onClick="changediv('cc_signup')" value="option2">
                <label for="radio2">
                 customers-2
                </label>
              </div>
            </div>
            <form class="fotm" id="cc_signup" style="display: none;" action="rfq.html">
              <div class="frm-btm-mrg">
                <div class="form-group">
                  <input class="form-control" placeholder="Email id" type="text">
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                  <input class="form-control" placeholder="Password"  type="password">
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                  <input class="form-control" placeholder="Re-enter password"  type="password">
                </div>

                <div class="form-group">
                  <input class="form-control" placeholder="Company name" type="text">
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                  <input class="form-control" placeholder="Website" type="text">
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                  <input class="form-control contact-num" placeholder="Contact number" type="text">
                </div>
                <div class="checkbox">
                  <input id="checkbox2" type="checkbox">
                  <label for="checkbox2">
                    I agree terms & conditions
                  </label>
                </div>
              </div>

              <button type="submit" class="btn">Sign up</button>
            </form>


            <form class="fotm" id="nc_signup" action="rfq.html">

              <div class="frm-btm-mrg-2">
                <div class="form-group">
                  <input class="form-control" placeholder="User name" type="text">
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                  <input class="form-control" placeholder="Email id" type="text">
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                  <input class="form-control" placeholder="Password"  type="password">
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                  <input class="form-control" placeholder="Re-enter password"  type="password">
                </div>
                <div class="checkbox">
                  <input id="checkbox3" type="checkbox">
                  <label for="checkbox3">
                    I agree terms & conditions
                  </label>
                </div>
              </div>

              <button type="submit" class="btn">Sign ups</button>
            </form>

          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Live code- [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-2vh8wc)

javascript

```
<script>  
    function changediv(divid){
        $("#nc_signup").hide();
        $("#cc_signup").hide();
        $("#"+ divid).show();

    }
</script>
```

```js
 function changediv(divid)
  {
    $("#nc_signup").hide();
    $("#cc_signup").hide();
    $("#"+ divid).show();

  }
```

```html
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <div class="modal fade cust-my-modal cust-my-modal-2" id="signup_modal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel">
      <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
        <div class="modal-content">
          <div class="modal-header">
            <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">×</span></button>
            <h4 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel">SIGN UP</h4>
          </div>
          <div class="modal-body">
            <div class="row">
              <div class="col-sm-12">
                <div class="top-radio">
                  <div class="radio radio-primary">
                    <input type="radio" name="radio1" id="radio1" onClick="changediv('nc_signup')" checked="checked" value="option1">
                    <label for="radio1">
                     customers-1
                    </label>
                  </div>
                  <div class="radio radio-primary">
                    <input type="radio" name="radio1" id="radio2" onClick="changediv('cc_signup')" value="option2">
                    <label for="radio2">
                     customers-2
                    </label>
                  </div>
                </div>
                <form class="fotm" id="cc_signup" style="display: none;" action="rfq.html">
                  <div class="frm-btm-mrg">
                    <div class="form-group">
                      <input class="form-control" placeholder="Email id" type="text">
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                      <input class="form-control" placeholder="Password"  type="password">
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                      <input class="form-control" placeholder="Re-enter password"  type="password">
                    </div>

                    <div class="form-group">
                      <input class="form-control" placeholder="Company name" type="text">
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                      <input class="form-control" placeholder="Website" type="text">
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                      <input class="form-control contact-num" placeholder="Contact number" type="text">
                    </div>
                    <div class="checkbox">
                      <input id="checkbox2" type="checkbox">
                      <label for="checkbox2">
                        I agree terms & conditions
                      </label>
                    </div>
                  </div>

                  <button type="submit" class="btn">Sign up</button>
                </form>


                <form class="fotm" id="nc_signup" action="rfq.html">

                  <div class="frm-btm-mrg-2">
                    <div class="form-group">
                      <input class="form-control" placeholder="User name" type="text">
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                      <input class="form-control" placeholder="Email id" type="text">
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                      <input class="form-control" placeholder="Password"  type="password">
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                      <input class="form-control" placeholder="Re-enter password"  type="password">
                    </div>
                    <div class="checkbox">
                      <input id="checkbox3" type="checkbox">
                      <label for="checkbox3">
                        I agree terms & conditions
                      </label>
                    </div>
                  </div>

                  <button type="submit" class="btn">Sign ups</button>
                </form>

              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Angular way to do this is to put code in app.component.ts instead of in a script-tag with jquery selectors.

You should have two member variables in your class that are changed by a method in the component.ts-fil, and bind to that method by using (click) in the HTML. To bind to variables in the code, use the [attr]-syntax.

You can take a look at my fork of your code here https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ktt3ri

Comment: Sir Thanks for the answer, but is it not my issue , can you please check my code snippet codes

Comment: I don't know what your issue is then, your snippet seems to work fine

Comment: Sir, click on this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52145682/angular-radio-button-click-show-and-hide-not-working/52146055?noredirect=1#comment91242108_52146055 ,you can understand it. is it working JS, but not working on Angular 5

Comment: I have looked at it. Have you looked at my link? I think I made it work for Angular 5

Comment: No problem :) I wish you the best of luck! I suggest that you read the angular.io docs about components